# How to get all the values selected in a multiselect ListBox in vb6?

Tags: vb6, listbox

I have a ListBox on my vb6 project and I've set its property to multiselect. 
Now, I want to get all of the selected items on my multiselect ListBox and put it in a variable for example, or maybe on a multiline textbox. I just wanted to get the multiselected values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately you must loop through all elements. Here is some sample code:

```
Dim k As Long
Dim s As String

For k = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
    If List1.Selected(k) Then
        s = List1.List(k)
        ' ... do something
    End If
Next
```